# How to use jQuery with Field?

Tags: javascript

I have Form alter for (loan) management.. If i want to add new loan i have to fill 3 fields .. (total_amount - installment_amount per month - installment_num) as the following code ..

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'loan_node_form') {
    $total_amount           = $form['field_total_amount']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
    $installment_amount     = $form['field_installment_amount']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
    $installment_num        = $form['field_installment_num']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
    $installment_num_res    = $total_amount/$installment_amount;
    $installment_amount_res = $total_amount/$installment_num;
    //Field for return $installment_amount_res
    if (empty($form['field_installment_num']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'])) {
        $form['field_installment_num']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $installment_num_res;
    }
    //Field for return $installment_num_res
    if (empty($form['field_installment_amount']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'])) {
        $form['field_installment_amount']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $installment_amount_res;
    }
}
```

How to get the result of any field before click save.. I think it something with `jQuery on change` but I haven't use any `jQuery` before..

Comment: First I would implement server side validation as a fallback when client side validation doesn't fire, or fails.

Comment: Also unrelated to drupal, but if you are performing math in PHP you might want to ensure the values are cast properly and use the `bcmath` set of functions to ensure accuracy (well as accurate as can be anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418999

I found this really helpful answer on stack overflow. This one is for dynamically created inputs. I assume that this is what you're after. You would retrieve the value for testing by using the .val() function.

```
//Static inputs
$('.fieldclass input').on('change', function (){
  $(this).val();
});
//Dynamic inputs (source above)
$(document).on('change', '.fieldclass input', function(){
  $('.fieldclass input').val();
});
```

There is also a shortcut for the on change method, as well really good documentation found here:
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Hope this is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with jQuery.

```
$('.form-actions input').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent normal submit action

  var fieldvalue = $('.field-name input').val(); //get the field value

  $('form#myForm').submit(); //submit the form

});
```

Hope it will help You. Ask if You need more help :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite correct.

Comment: @Kevin Do You have better answers? Or can You tell why you're not sure if it's correct?

Comment: I don't believe this is what's being asked. Dropping that exact code in doesn't change his situation (I think) and is best handled with form Ajax and validation I believe.